# Insert XML data into mongoDB using scala?

Tags: xml, list, scala, object

I'm new about Scala. What I want to do is retrieving data from a XML file, and keeping the data into a list, finally inserting them into mongodb collection. I have some problems. I know the way of steps, but I couldn't apply in the codes. I thought I should have had a class which is class Contact, and it includes fields(name, lastName, phone). I want to take name, lastName and phone data in labels by one by, and assign them to Contact objects. After getting operation, I should write these data into mongoDb.

**Class Contact**

```
class Contact(_name: String, _lastName: String, _phones: String) {

/* Fields */
//var id: Int           = _id
var name: String      = _name
var lastName: String  = _lastName
var phones: String    = _phones
```

I use a function to get xml file data.

```
def GetXMLFile(){
val contacts = XML.loadFile("xmlFilePath")
assert(contacts.isInstanceOf[scala.xml.Elem])
var persons: List[Contact] = new Contact()
for (name <- (contacts\\ "name"))
```

After that I'm stocked. Can anyone help me a little? I'll really be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [salat](https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki). This is a library written in scala wrapped over [casbah](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/) Java driver for MongoDB.

The DAO [wiki](https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/SalatDAO) page would particualrly be of interest for you, it can directly serialize a case class to an object in the mongo collection.

```
case class Alpha(@Key("_id") id: Int, x: String)

object AlphaDAO extends SalatDAO[Alpha, Int](collection = MongoConnection()("test_db")("test_coll"))

val alpha1 = Alpha(id = 1, x = "alpha1")
// if everything went OK, this method will return Some(1)
val _id = AlphaDAO.insert(alpha1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much anoopelias.